# CAAnimation - incorrect interpretation of `transform`?

Tags: ios, caanimation, cakeyframeanimation

I'm running into some very weird behavior with CAAnimation that I'm trying to understand. I've managed to boil it down to a simple reproduction case:

- Create a simple `CAKeyframeAnimation` with `keyPath="transform"`
- Create a `CATransform3D` which is any multiple of the identity matrix (except 0 or 1). Let's say `0.5I` for this example, so every diagonal entry is 0.5.
- Set this matrix as the value for any number of frames.
- Add the animation to some view's layer.

(Sorry, I'm working in Xamarin, so unfortunately no copy-paste Swift / ObjC code sample; I have exactly zero experience in these languages).

If you assign the transform I just described to a layer directly through (`layer.transform = transform`) it behaves as expected - nothing happens. The matrix is a multiple of the identity matrix, so after division over the homogeneous coordinate input / output points should be identical. As key frames of an animation, however, the matrix scales the layer to half its size (or whatever factor you chose).

I am stumped as to why this is happening and am hoping somebody can shed some light on this situation.

Comment: I couldnt really understand but shouldnt 0.5I matrix supposed to halve the size?

Comment: 4D (and 3D) homogeneous transformations are identical up to a scale factor because the result vectors are divided by their homogeneous coordinate. So, no, if `m44 = 0.5` as well, this is supposed to be an identity transformation in 3D space (in 4D space you would be right). To make sure I'm not going crazy about that I tried setting it as a regular transform property, which as I mentioned works as expected.